# Adding a character before a specific character in a String (JS)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append a character ('\') before a specific character (") in a given string. This is my function:

```
    function addChar(test){
      var txt2=""
       for(i=0; i<test.length; i++){
        if(test[i] === '"'){
         txt2 += test.slice(i-1,i) + '\\' ;
        }
       }
    return txt2
```

When I call the function on this string:

```
let string = '"'+'STR1'+'"' + " "+ "AND" +" "+ '"' + 'STR2' + '"' \\ ("STR1" AND "STR2")
```

it returns `\1\ \2\` but I want `\\"STR1\\" AND \\"STR2\\"`. How can I fix my code in order to print this out?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `String.prototype.replace`? `originalString.replace(/"/g, '\\"')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend iterating over all string characters, that's not readable and very error-prone. Try instead matching all double quotes, and replace them by `\"`. Note the use of `//g` to match *all* quotes, and the use of `\\` instead of `\` to escape the `\`.

```js
console.log('"STR1" AND "STR2"'.replace(/"/g, '\\"'));
```

Answer (score -1):

How about just doing a replace?

```js
let string = '"' + 'STR1'+'"' + " "+ "AND" +" "+ '"' + 'STR2' + '"'; // ("STR1" AND "STR2") 

string = string.replace(/"/g,'\\\\"');

console.log(string);
```

Comment: That only replaces the first occurrence and replaces it with `"` instead of `\"`

Comment: @NinoFiliu Answer updated and original does replace `"` with `\"`.